# Python/Pandas change date format for date_range index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am running a script (*script 1*) to create an empty data frame which is populated by another script (*script 2*). The index in this empty data frame is a time series of 30 minute intervals across 365 days, beginning 1st October 2016. To create this time series index, *Script 1* contains the following code:

```
time_period_start = dt.datetime(2016,01,10).strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
index = pd.date_range(time_period_start, freq='30min', periods=17520)
```

*Script 2* pulls data out of a CSV file, containing values across a time series. The plan is for this script to put this data into a dataframe, and then merge this with the dataframe created in *Script 1*.

The problem I am having is that the format of the dates in the dataframe created in *Script 2* is Y-D-M, which is what comes out of the CSV files. However, the format of the dates in the dataframe created in *Script 1* is Y-M-D, which causes incorrect results when I try to merge. This is even despite my use of ".strftime("%Y-%d-%m")" in the first line of code above. Is there any way of amending the second line of code so that the output dataframe is in Y-D-M?

Comment: If you set the dtype to `datetime` for both dfs then the merge will just work, using `strftime` will give you a string which has no knowledge of which components are day or month, you're better off keeping everything as datetime and passing the correct format for the conversion so the merge works correctly

Comment: Thanks. That's working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.strftime()` isn't affecting the final dataframe, since `pd.date_range` transforms it back into a `datetime` anyway.  Instead of trying to match on strings, you should convert the dates in the second dataframe (the one created by Script 2) to `datetime` as well.

```
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date, format='%Y-%d-%m')
```